# Deploy customized Stack Overflow app in local

Tags: discussion

Is there a way that I can get a version of the Stack Overflow application to deploy it at our organization and use it?

(an official localized Stack Overflow application)

Answer (score 3):

No, the software is not available for use outside of Stack Exchange.

Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88753

> Stack Exchange no longer offers a subscription service nor licenses the software to host your own Stack Exchange sites. Stack Exchange sites can only be created through the democratic, community-driven process at Area 51.

Comment: That said, there are quite a few clones out there. [Stack Overflow clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267)